# Returning booleans in a C# method

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of booleans which gets filled by a loop. The method that owns the array needs to return a single boolean. So can I do this:

```
bool[] Booleans = new bool[4];

// do work - fill array

return (Booleans[0] && Booleans[1] && Booleans[2] && Booleans[3]);
```

So if I have: `T,T,F,T` will I get `F` back since there is one in the array or will it send back something else or just crash all together?

Comment: Fine approach, until you change the number of items in the array, then the loop approach as @James's answer below.

Comment: Off topic because I'm now really not happy with @Mark for editing my question and removing half of my sentences when I was not vulgar in any way. I just don't understand what the thought process there was?

Comment: It was nothing to do with being vulgar, I removed it because it added no value and if you look at the question summary which only shows the first two lines all you could see is just random waffling that has nothing to do with the question. And if you want to thank someone for answering your question then write to them in a comment under their answer. They will appreciate it a lot more if it is a personal thank-you.

Comment: And if you wish to discuss whether or not my edit was inappropriate then a better venue for this discussion is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/. You can ask a question there about it (or search for similar questions that have been answered before).

Comment: Ok, now I can understand why you did it, but you have to understand that from my point of view my question was changed without so much as an explanation. I'm sure you wouldn't be happy if the same was done to you. Anyway, thanks for explaining why you did it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A single `false` will result in `false` being returned with boolean `AND` logic.

You can also rewrite as:

```
return Booleans.All(b => b);
```

For the sake of completeness, or if LINQ is not an option, you can achieve the same via a loop:

```
var list = new List<bool> { true, false, true };

bool result = true;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    result &= item;
    if (!item)
        break;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

For small samples what you have is fine, but as the number of items grow either of the above approaches will make the code a lot friendlier.

Comment: I think `All` is a bit overkill here.

Comment: I haven't used `All` before. Can you explain what it does exactly? And how would it differ (be better than?) from `Any` in this case?

Comment: All requires that each item be true, while Any requires that one item be true - logical AND of items VS logical OR. In this case, you want All, since all elements in the array should be true for true to be returned.

Comment: @Alex `All` is used to check that all the items meet a given criteria. Since you're dealing with booleans you would want to use `All` and check that they're all `true` as my snippet shows. `Any` is used to check that at least one item (i.e., any item) meets a given criteria. You don't want to use `Any` in this case since it wouldn't take all the elements into consideration but only return true as soon as any item meets the criteria.

Comment: `All` is the more restrictive brother of `Any`. It simply verifies that all elements of a sequence match a given criteria. You could use either in this case, though with opposite tests. Use `All` as demonstrated to verify all values are true, or `Any` to verify if at least one is false (and  return false if so).

Comment: @Remi, @Ahmad and @Anthony, okay now `All` makes sense to me. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Can't you just use !Booleans.Contains(false) then?

Comment: @Nyerguds you could but it doesn't seem as clear with the `NOT` logic attached. `All` also makes it easier to check certain properties when not dealing with a sequence of booleans directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you must process the array and return only a single boolean, then the best approach would be to just set a value to true, then loop through until the value is false, or you reach the end of the loop.

This way you won't have to process past the first false value, since that makes the entire result false.

How you loop through depends on which version of .NET you are using.