# check whether array contains false?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, .net-2.0, contains

How to check the array `true_or_false`  containing a value of false?

```
bool[] true_or_false = new bool[10];

for (int i = 0; i < txtbox_and_message.Length; i++)
{
  bool bStatus = true;
  if (txtbox_and_message[i] == "")
  {
    bStatus = false;
  }
  true_or_false[i] = bStatus;                           
}
```

Comment: What is the loop doing? Looks like it checks for blank text (repeatedly) and sets *all* elements either true, or false if the string is blank?

Comment: Shouldn't `bStatus` depend somehow on `i`?  This is why PaulG correctly says that all elements are the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning booleans in a C# method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852078/returning-booleans-in-a-c-method)

Comment: Are you missing txtStarter=txtbox_and_message[i]; ? Or what Ben said? Your code obviously contains errors.

Comment: I have modified my question..

Comment: It still doesnt make sense! If you're iterating the length of txtbox_and_message, then txtbox_and_message[i] will never be ""

Comment: @PaulG: Not so.  The `.Length` is the number of strings in the array, not the length of any particular string.

Comment: @Ben, ah yes - makes sense now! I thought txtbox_and_message was a single string rather than an array, and krunal was trying to check characters in the string. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If they are not all true, then at least one is false.

Therefore:

```
!true_or_false.All(x => x)
```

Docu: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx

EDIT: .NET 2.0 version, as requested:

```
!Array.TrueForAll(true_or_false, delegate (bool x) { return x; })
```

or

```
Array.Exists(true_or_false, delegate (bool x) { return !x; })
```

NOTE: I've been staying away from the nonsensical code that sets `true_or_false`, but it could be that what you want is:

```
int emptyBox = Array.FindIndex(txtbox_and_message, string.IsNullOrEmpty);
```

which will give you -1 if all the strings are non-empty, or the index of the failing string otherwise.

Comment: No, the extension method syntax and lambda notation for the predicate both need C# 3, but a .NET 2 version does exist (see edit).

Comment: You do not really need delegates (anonymous function or lambda) for this. You can do `Array.Contains(true_or_false, false)` which comes very close to the title (check if array contains false). That is on .NET 2.0. When you have LINQ, you can also use the syntax `true_or_false.Contains(false)`. _EDIT:_ WRONG! In .NET 2.0, you have to do `Array.IndexOf(true_or_false, false) != -1` instead.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Sure but my answer shows that the index can be found without having to prepare the array of booleans in advance, which I considered to be better than searching the array of booleans.

Answer (score 11):

```
return true_or_false.Any(p => !p);
```

Comment: Unfortunately No, it needs 3.0 +

Comment: @krunal: If you have platform restrictions, you should put them in the question.

Answer (score 10):

```
using System.Linq;
```

then:

```
true_or_false.Contains(false);
```

Comment: I am getting this error after adding System.Linq. The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add a reference in your project to system.core dll

Comment: LINQ comes with .NET 3.5 and VS 2008 so you will need to use an iterative solution such as Pavan or BrunoLM's answers

Answer (score 2):

**Intead of your code:**

```
bool containsEmptyText = txtbox_and_message.Contains( t => t.Text ==String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of solutions:

**Solution 1:**
do a for loop after that for loop to check if the true_or_false contains false like this:

if you want to achieve this without fancy tricks, and you want to program the code yourself you can do this:

```
bool containsFalse = false;
for(int j = 0; j < true_or_false.Length; j++)
{
   //if the current element the array is equals to false, then containsFalse is true,
   //then exit for loop
   if(true_or_false[j] == false){
       containsFalse = true;
       break;
   }
}

if(containsFalse) {
  //your true_or_false array contains a false then.
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
!true_or_false.All(x => x);
```

**PK**

Comment: `== false` and `== true` need to die. Otherwise a good answer +1.

Comment: Your second solution would perform better if you used `true_or_false.Any(x => !x)`

Comment: @nasufara: On what evidence do you base this claim?  Both `Any` and `All` are short-circuiting.  If anything, the need to call the `!` (boolean NOT) operator only once should make `All` faster, but the difference is almost certainly too small to measure.

Comment: @Pavan: you can make method #1 faster by adding `break;` inside the if, as you don't need to keep looking after you found the first false.

Comment: thanks a lot guys. @Billy ive made the changes. and @ben, yes thats right. I've made the changes. thank you once again

Comment: there was a platform restriction with the person asking the question so i didnt put the third solution up. Ive made the changes though. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If on .NET3.5+ you can use `System.Linq`, and then check using [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
// if it contains any false element it will return true
true_or_false.Any(x => !x); // !false == true
```

If you can't use Linq, then you have other choises:

Using `Array.Exists` static method: (as Ben mentioned)

```
Array.Exists(true_or_false, x => !x);
```

Using [`List.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (you would have to convert the array to a list to access this method)

```
true_or_falseList.Exists(x => !x);
```

Or you will need to iterate through the array.

```
foreach (bool b in true_or_false)
{
    if (!b) return true; // if b is false return true (it contains a 'false' element)
}
return false; // didn't find a 'false' element
```

---

Related

- [Linq .Any VS .Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879391/linq-any-vs-exists-whats-the-difference)

---

And optimizing your code:

```
bool[] true_or_false = new bool[10];

for (int i = 0; i < txtbox_and_message.Length; i++)
{
    true_or_false[i] = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox_and_message[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why are you reaching for `List.Exists` instead of `Array.Exists`?